# Дополнительные поля modx revo

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

Всем привет, сделал доп. поля на форме по этому [уроку](https://ilyaut.ru/tips-and-tricks/process-form-fields-added-dynamically/).

После нажатия на форме сохранить значения инпут сохраняются в tv поля, но в tv оно записывается вот в таком виде, если несколько дополнительных полей
`Независимости 15||Независимости 16`. Как мне выводить по отдельности:

```
Независимости 15
Независимости 16Пробовал вот так
[[+tv.adress.0]] но не выводит ничего
```